# Query eloquent with 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a products table with this fields:

> id, name, idCategory

And a category table:

> id, name

I want the method to return all the fields in the product table, but instead of the product id, I want it show me the name of this. I know how make it with SQL but not with eloquent.
The purpose is to return a JSON because I am doing an API with laravel.

Comment: What SQL query would you use to achieve this?

Comment: SELECT products.id, products.name, category.name FROM `products` JOIN category ON products.id=category.id;

Comment: Are you familiar with Eloquent relationships?

Comment: A little bit yes, i'm practised, now im try this:  $products = Products::join('Category','idCategory', '=', 'Category.id')->select('Products.id', 'Products.name','Category.name')->get();
But it does not show the name of the product...

Comment: You have to add an alias for the second `name` column: `Category.name as category_name`

Comment: Ok, now it works, thanks. You know how it works with 'hasmany' and 'belongsto'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with Eloquent relationships:

```
class Product {
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'idCategory');
    }
}

$products = Product::with('category')->get();
```